# MYSQL - return the minimum number of records so price sum is possible to be as close to the input price

Tags: mysql, aggregate, sum

I have a table with names, prices and a user input price, for example, 100.

I want to return a minimum number of records so prices sum will be close to the input price

So If I have in records items with prices of 500,200,50,45 and 30;

must be return records with 50 and 45 in case of 100;

Comment: *I want to return a minimum number of records so prices sum will be close to the input price* What is the priority - minimal rows amount or minimal difference? Close - strictly below or doesn't matter? And what is precise MySQL version? show output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: @Akina close - strictly below with the price.

8.0.27

Comment: @Motta it is just an example to better understand. user input price 100. I must return 2 items with prices 50 and 45 because 95 will be closet with 100.

if there is an item with a price of 100. then I must return 1 item

Comment: Suggest you use your app language.  SQL is not a good tool for such an algorithm.  I have a good algorithm, but it involves two pointers marching through the sorted list.  I cringe at the thought of having to do it in SQL (which does not like walking through lists).

Comment: A variation of Knapsack_problem  ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, weight, CAST(id AS CHAR(255)) path
  FROM test
  WHERE weight <= @sum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test.id, test.weight + cte.weight, CONCAT(cte.path, ',', test.id)
  FROM cte
  JOIN test ON test.id > cte.id
  WHERE test.weight + cte.weight <= @sum
)
SELECT COALESCE(test.id, 'total'), SUM(weight)
FROM (
  SELECT path
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY weight DESC, LENGTH(path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(path, ',', '')) ASC LIMIT 1
  ) optimal
JOIN test ON FIND_IN_SET(test.id, optimal.path)
GROUP BY test.id WITH ROLLUP
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/HkkEAa2Q

The query selects the most closest to `@sum` but not above summary weight rowset. If there is more than one such set then the shortest one is returned. If more than one set have the same length then indefinite of them is returned.

If `CHAR(255)` is not enough for complete path then increase the length.